# grails 2.4.2 - timepoint of validation of domain object

Tags: validation, grails

I have got a domain class with some custom validators like the following:

```
class Domain {
    String attribute1
    OtherDomain attribute2

    static constraints = {
        attribute2 nullable: true, validator: {OtherDomain od, Domain d ->
            if (od) {
                log.debug "entering validation"
                // certain validation here
            }
    }
}
```

For updating I have got a simple action in the corresponding `DomainController`:

```
@Transactional
def update(Domain domainInstance) {
    log.debug "entering update()"
    // rest of update
}
```

I'm wondering why in my `debuglog` I get the debug messages in the following order:

1. `entering validation`
2. `entering update()`

The problem is that the validation fails at this point (`StackOverflowError`). I know the reason for this error and I know what to do to circumvent this error (doing so within `update` action). However, I don't know why there is a validation before the programme even gets into the `update()` action. And I don't know how to prevent a validation at this point.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you see the "entering validation" message before "entering update()" is because you have declared a command object of type `Domain`. This means that Grails will bind any request parameters to `domainInstance` and then call `validate()` on it, *before the action is executed*. This allows you to write code like this:

```
@Transactional
def update(Domain domainInstance) {
    // at this point request params have been bound and validate() has 
    // been executed, so any validation errors will be available in
    // domainInstance.errors

    if (domainInstance.hasErrors() {
        // do something
    }

    log.debug "entering update()"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation! As I re-read the documentation about data-binding I found it as well, here: [Grails Documentation - Validating Constraints: Validation Phases](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#validatingConstraints)